# Cross domain request with JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying cross domain request from my js file.

First,I was trying JSONP but  my target domain URL is not support it. It return plain JSON object.

I am authorize person to access my target domain URL. but i can not modify it as per JSONP response.

SO how can i get JSON response from my target domain URL?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, server doesn't wrap JSON object with passed callback function name?

Comment: Shad: Yes,you are correct. Server send JSON only

Answer (score 1):

I have always done it with jsonp, by passing a callback b/c services return json, if call back is passed then it will wrap all json in callback else they will simple return json.

But in your case

You can look up with this article 
http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/cross-domain-browser-json-ajax/

Comment: How does that answer the question? He clearly states tha he cannot use JSONP.

Comment: Dear friend @freakish, that's why i did not mention any jsonp example, i give a link where you can work with json only, link provide  a tute to work with json on cross domain call. why did u negate that? it is clear in link that  **cross-domain-browser-json-ajax/** not jsonp. and sorry i forgot to not mention **But in your case** in answer.

Comment: Not at all, b/c my answer did not say that, it is about json not jsonp . so i improved it.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying a bit the server side there is not much you can do. The general policy is to not to allow cross domain requests.

There are few things worth mentioning though:

1. Try changing the server side so it will support JSONP.
2. If the HTTP response contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header then you can communicate with it with normal AJAX. This feature is supported in modern browsers only. [Check this out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for more info.
3. You can do the cross domain requests with Flash and/or WebSockets. However server does have to support them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what type application you are developing. But in ASP.NET you can do it by using a proxy page

These links may be helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667611/ASP-NET-Proxy-Page-Used-for-Cross-Domain-Requests

http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/

https://gist.github.com/jkresner/3982746